# PROBLEMA CON ACCESO A APLICACIONES A TRAVES DE RDSWEB GATEWAY y usando Hml5 client

Tags: windows-server

Tengo un problema al momento de ejecutar aplicaciones remotas en rdweb access usando el cliente html5, el servidor es 2022. Hemos desplegado todos los servicios de RDS en una sola maquina incluida la puerta de enlace, hemos desplegado el cliente html5 en el servidor via powershell. El portal de acceso a aplicaciones se depliega adecuadamente con:

https://nombredeldominio/RDWeb/webclient/index.html

Pide usuario y contreña se autentica, muestra las aplicaciones publicadas.

Pero al momento de hacer click sobre cualquier app publicada, sale el ste error:

Se perdió la conexión al equipo remoto. Esto puede ser debido a un problema de conexión de red. Si sigues teniendo problemas, pide ayuda a tu administrador o a soporte técnico.

Los puertos se cambian por propiedades de la puerta de enlace para https y por
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp